# Coldfusion structure and/or arrays to organize some data

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, structure

Creating a birthday club.

The database consists of clients and their pets.  Some clients may only have 1 pet whereas others may have 10. `Clients` are stored in one table and `Pets` in another table with `client_id` as the primary and foreign key accordingly.

The web page will show hundreds of clients and their pets but we'll focus on one dummy record named John Doe.  Now, lets say John Doe has a dog, a horse, and a cat.  The dog and cat have birthdays in January and the horse in March.  When I view the web page, I can see John's cat and dog with the input box checked but not for the horse (since his birthday is in March and not January).  I click the "proceed" button and an email will be generated to John wishing his dog and cat a happy birthday but I don't want to include the horse.  He'll get another email in March for the horse but not for the cat.  With me so far?

Now, my form, I have setup like this:

```
<cfset ClientPet = ArrayNew(2)>  
<cfoutput>  
<cfset x = 1>  
<cfloop index="p" list="#select_pet#" delimiters=",">  
Client ID: #listfirst(p,'|')#<br />  
Pet ID: #listlast(p,'|')#  
<cfset ArrayAppend(ClientPet[x][1], '#listfirst(p,'|')#')>  
<cfset ArrayAppend(ClientPet[x][2], '#listlast(p,'|')#')>  
</cfloop>  
</cfoutput>
```

On the action page, I'd like to only send one email to a client and dynamically list their pets but only the pets that were selected from the previous page so I'm doing this:

```
<cfset ClientPet = ArrayNew(2)>  
<cfoutput>  
<cfset x = 1>  
<cfloop index="p" list="#select_pet#" delimiters=",">  
Client ID: #listfirst(p,'|')#<br />  
Pet ID: #listlast(p,'|')#  
<cfset ArrayAppend(ClientPet[x][1], '#listfirst(p,'|')#')>  
<cfset ArrayAppend(ClientPet[x][2], '#listlast(p,'|')#')>  
</cfloop>  
</cfoutput>
```

I don't know if I should use Arrays or structures and whichever way I do it, I need to be able to loop over all of the client_id and then all of the pets, then the next client_id and all of their pets, and so on.  Am I on the right path above?  If so, I should be able to loop over my 2d array or structure and then systematically list the pets accordingly, right?

Comment: Is the goal to create a email to all of the clients wishing a happy brithday to their pets for the current month?  why are you showing the check boxes?  Is this going to be a scheduled task?

Comment: @NathanStanford - my customer wanted to untick a checkbox if she didn't want the client to receive an email notice (e.g. the pet passed and she just hadn't marked the pet as deceased yet).

Comment: @NathanStanford - Are you the same Nathan from EasyCFM by chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As Nathan suggested, this might be a better candidate for a scheduled task rather than a manual form*.

.. But to address the question about arrays and structures .. it does not sound like you need either one. Just make the checkbox value the `petid` value.

```
<input name="select_pet" type="checkbox" value="#petID#">
```

When the form is submitted, the field will contain a list of the selected pet id's. Just feed that list into a query to retrieve both the client and pet information.

```
   SELECT  c.client_name, p.pet_id, p.pet_name
   FROM    pet p INNER JOIN clients c ON c.client_id = p.client_id
   WHERE   p.pet_id IN 
   ( 
      <cfqueryparam value="#form.select_pet#" list="true" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer"> 
   )
```

Comment: That is the route we ended up going with.  I was making this way harder than necessary.  I'm not sure why I thought I needed the client_ID to be passed, too but you are 100% correct, I just need to look up the client_id since I have the petID.  Using the group by:  `SELECT     p.id, p.pet_name, p.pet_dob, c.client_id, c.fn, c.ln, c.email
FROM         vet_release_pets AS p INNER JOIN
                      customer AS c ON p.vet_release_key = c.client_key
GROUP BY p.id, p.pet_name, p.pet_dob, c.client_id, c.fn, c.ln, c.email
HAVING      (p.id IN (#select_pet#))
ORDER BY c.client_id`

Comment: I'm setting up an email using scheduled task to remind my client to go out and run the report.  :)

Comment: (Edit) I am not sure about the report :) But would it not be easier to just send the emails automatically - no human intervention required? Regarding the sql, it is usually more efficient to filter in the `WHERE` clause, not the `HAVING`. Just be sure to use `cfqueryparam list=true`. It looks like you could eliminate the `GROUP BY` too, since there are no aggregates.

Comment: Oh, never mind about the first part. I see from the later comments above you need a final "review" prior to sending the emails.